# Swift multiple scenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have made a swift `SpriteKit` game but now I want to add a menu scene(and eventually a lose scene). So what I did was

1. I created a new scene called Menu scene.
2. I edited `GameViewController` and changed it to load menu scene(it worked).
3. In **MenuScene.swift** I put some code in so when a sprite was clicked it would run this code:

   ```
   let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)

   let scene = GameScene(size: size)

   self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
   ```

But when I click the button it flips round to the next scene and immediately crashes.

So my question is: Am I doing this the right way and if I am why does it crash?

Comment: what crash do you get, can you post your scene code

Comment: What do you mean "scene code"? I know that the scenes work because I can set GameViewController to load them by default and it works.

Comment: an you post the error you get and the log

Comment: Try enabling break on exceptions by `Debug > Breakpoint > Create Exception Breakpoint`. Also, I suggest you set a break point on the first statement of `didMoveToView` in GameScene.m to see where it crashes.

Comment: When it crashes it goes to the first line of AppDelegate.swift with the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)". By the way its swift.

Comment: Something else is causing it to break,  probably on the deinit of MenuScreen, you have something like a timer or listener that is expecting Menu to be alive, but since it is not alive, it is crashing,  Could you post your MenuScene class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't deleting a particle emitter so I put in a bit of code to delete it just before the transition and it worked.

Comment: You can always override deinit when you need for things like this to be removed prior to the deallocation of an object

Answer (score -1):

If you do, it should work:

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
let scene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
let skView = view as SKView!
skView.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: This adds nothing to the code except force view to not be null.  It does not solve the problem, it just adds a reason for the game to just crash

Answer (score -2):

Since you're in sprite kit , it's wrong to use :

```
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

You should do the following  :

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
let skView = view as SKView

//skView.showsFPS = true
//skView.showsNodeCount = true
//skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
//scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

skView.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

Comment: When i put that in there were 2 errors 1. SKView? does not have a member named bounds 2. Downcast SKView? to SKView only unwraps optionals;did you mean to use !? When i did correct those errors by changing view.bounds.size to just size and view as SKView to view! it just crashed the minute I clicked?

Comment: How is his way "wrong"?  It is not a way I would prefer, but it is actually more valid then the answer you have provided.  In the OP code, if the view is nil, the code will not crash, and can be handled later on, in your code, you have to enforce that view is not nil in some way, which is not posted here.